# SwiftUI Sign in with Apple button dark mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, sign-in-with-apple

I have implemented Sign in with Apple but the thing is that the button is always black. I would like to show it in light/ dark mode depending on the users phone.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
import SwiftUI
import CryptoKit
import FirebaseAuth
import AuthenticationServices

struct SignInWithAppleButtonView: View {
    @State var currentNonce:String?
    
    var body: some View {
        SignInWithAppleButton(
            onRequest: { request in
                let nonce = randomNonceString()
                currentNonce = nonce
                request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
                request.nonce = sha256(nonce)
            },
            onCompletion: { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let authResults):
                    switch authResults.credential {
                    case let appleIDCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:
                        
                        guard let nonce = currentNonce else {
                            fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
                        }
                        guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
                            fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
                        }
                        guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
                            print("Unable to serialize token string from data: \(appleIDToken.debugDescription)")
                            return
                        }
                        
                        let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",idToken: idTokenString,rawNonce: nonce)
                        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
                            if (error != nil) {
                                // Error. If error.code == .MissingOrInvalidNonce, make sure
                                // you're sending the SHA256-hashed nonce as a hex string with
                                // your request to Apple.
                                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                                return
                            }
                            print("signed in")
                        }
                        
                        print("\(String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid))")
                    default:
                        break
                        
                    }
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices
struct SignInWithAppleButtonView: View{
    var body: some View{
        
        DynamicAppleSignIn(
            onRequest: { request in
                //Your Code
            },
            onCompletion: { result in
                switch result {
                case .success (let authResults):
                    print("Authorization successful.")
                // Your Code
                case .failure (let error):
                    print("Authorization failed: \(error)")
                // Your Code
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
struct DynamicAppleSignIn : View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    var onRequest: (ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest) -> Void
    var onCompletion: ((Result<ASAuthorization, Error>) -> Void)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        switch colorScheme {
        case .dark:
            SignInWithAppleButton(
                onRequest: onRequest,
                onCompletion: onCompletion
            ).signInWithAppleButtonStyle(.white)
            .frame(minWidth: 140, maxWidth: 240, minHeight: 30,  maxHeight: 60, alignment: .center)
        case .light:
            SignInWithAppleButton(
                onRequest: onRequest,
                onCompletion: onCompletion
            ).signInWithAppleButtonStyle(.black)
            .frame(minWidth: 140, maxWidth: 240, minHeight: 30,  maxHeight: 60, alignment: .center)
        @unknown default:
            fatalError("Not Yet Implemented")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but I need to close and reopen the app in order for it to work. any idea why?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that was a thing apparently there is a bug report out there for it since the beginning. I posted a workaround.

Comment: I will leave the original answer for now. Probably will be fixed in the next SwiftUI update.

Comment: Just wanted to let people know that it's 2023 out there and this bug is not yet fixed, i.e. one still needs to implement a `DynamicAppleSignIn` button in order to make it dynamically react to the color scheme change...

Answer (score 2):

At first add

@Environment(.colorScheme) var colorScheme

and then add the style depends of variable

.signInWithAppleButtonStyle(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)

In your case, it would look like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import CryptoKit
import FirebaseAuth
import AuthenticationServices

struct SignInWithAppleButtonView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State var currentNonce:String?

    var body: some View {
        SignInWithAppleButton(
            onRequest: { request in
                let nonce = randomNonceString()
                currentNonce = nonce
                request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
                request.nonce = sha256(nonce)
            },
            onCompletion: { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let authResults):
                    switch authResults.credential {
                    case let appleIDCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:

                        guard let nonce = currentNonce else {
                            fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
                        }
                        guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
                            fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
                        }
                        guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
                            print("Unable to serialize token string from data: \(appleIDToken.debugDescription)")
                            return
                        }

                        let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",idToken: idTokenString,rawNonce: nonce)
                        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
                            if (error != nil) {
                                // Error. If error.code == .MissingOrInvalidNonce, make sure
                                // you're sending the SHA256-hashed nonce as a hex string with
                                // your request to Apple.
                                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                                return
                            }
                            print("signed in")
                        }

                        print("\(String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid))")
                    default:
                        break

                    }
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        )
        .signInWithAppleButtonStyle(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
    }
}
```