# Setting Apple SSO button dimensions in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I can't figure out how to make this apple sign-in button wider and taller.  no matter where I try to add `.frame(width: ....` it just seems to move the button around the screen. But, does not alter the dimensions of the button itself.

This is in ContentView.swift:

```
struct ContentView : View {
      @State var credentials: CredentialsOrError?
      var body: some View {
        VStack {
          if $credentials.wrappedValue == nil {
            SignInWithAppleButton(credentials: $credentials)
          }
          else if $credentials.wrappedValue!.isSuccess
          {
            Text("User: \($credentials.wrappedValue!.values!.user)")
            Text("Given name: \($credentials.wrappedValue!.values?.givenName ?? "")")
            Text("Family name: \($credentials.wrappedValue!.values?.familyName ?? "")")
            Text("Email: \($credentials.wrappedValue!.values?.email  ?? "")")
          }
          else {
            Text($credentials.wrappedValue!.error!.localizedDescription).foregroundColor(.red)
          }
        }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: .constant($credentials.wrappedValue != nil && $credentials.wrappedValue!.isSuccess) , content: {
            HomeView()
        })
      }
}
```

This is from `SignInWithAppleButton.swift`:

```
struct SignInWithAppleButton: View {
  
  @Binding var credentials: CredentialsOrError?
    
  var body: some View {
    
    let button = ButtonController(credentials: $credentials)
                                    
    return button
        .frame(width: button.button.frame.width, height: button.button.frame.height, alignment: .center)
  }
  
  struct ButtonController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let button: ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()
    let vc: UIViewController = UIViewController()
    
    @Binding var credentials: CredentialsOrError?

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
      return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
      vc.view.addSubview(button)
      return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) { }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate, ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {
      let parent: ButtonController
      
      init(_ parent: ButtonController) {
        self.parent = parent
        
        super.init()
        
        parent.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton), for: .touchUpInside)
      }
      
      @objc func didTapButton() {
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        
        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
      }
      
      func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        return parent.vc.view.window!
      }
      
      func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        guard let credentials = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential else {
          parent.credentials = .error("Credentials are not of type ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential")
          return
        }
        
        parent.credentials = .credentials(user: credentials.user, givenName: credentials.fullName?.givenName, familyName: credentials.fullName?.familyName, email: credentials.email)
      }
      
      func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
        parent.credentials = .error(error)

      }
    }
  }

}
```

Attached is a picture of what it looks like currently on my dark mode iPhone and I've also attached a picture of the light mode emulator.

Related question: How can I hard code the background of the screen to be white?

In the emulator:

[image: emulator]

On my dark mode iPhone:

[image: dark mode]

Comment: Please share the code for ButtonController. The problem is likely in there.

Comment: @Adam added to my original post

Comment: The dark mode thing is a known issue and the view has to be redrawn as far as the sizing issue it is likely because of how you have written your `UIViewController` you likely need to create a complete `UIViewController` and pin the view to the edges so you can modify the size. SwiftUI has its own Apple sign in button. At a simple glance I don't see any special code in yours. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65400766/swiftui-sign-in-with-apple-button-dark-mode/65815742#65815742) for a sample