# Sign in with Apple Button only changes colour scheme when app is restarted

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have my sign in with apple button, with dark and light more support as shown:

```
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices

final class SignInWithApple: UIViewRepresentable {
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton {
    return ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(authorizationButtonType: .default, authorizationButtonStyle: UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? .white : .black)
  }
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton, context: Context) {
  }
}
```

However, when I change apperance whilst the app is in the background, the button's colour scheme does not change, I have to restart the app to update it's colour scheme, I have no idea why this isn't built into it, but any ideas?

Comment: It is a known thing the view has to be redrawn. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65400766/swiftui-sign-in-with-apple-button-dark-mode/65815742#65815742

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI Sign in with Apple button dark mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65400766/swiftui-sign-in-with-apple-button-dark-mode)